# Why Bigquery's standardsql returns multiple rows while legacysql just one?

Tags: google-bigquery

Could you help me a bit with Bigquery's standardsql syntax question, please?
I'm trying to understand why (and how to fix it) this standardsql query   returns 2 rows while this legacysql one returns just 1 (and i expect just one).

**StandardSQL**

```
  SELECT 
  hits2.transaction.transactionId as transactionId
  FROM `ga-export-TTTT.1234567890.ga_sessions_*`
  ,UNNEST (hits) as hits2

WHERE 
hits2.transaction.transactionId = '03971163'
```

**LegacySQL**

```
select
hits.transaction.transactionId
FROM
 TABLE_DATE_RANGE([ga-export-TTTT:1234567890.ga_sessions_], TIMESTAMP('2016-09-01'), TIMESTAMP('2017-02-14'))
WHERE 
hits.transaction.transactionId = '03971163'
```

After reading help I also tried this **StandardSQL** one with the same two rows in the results:

```
select 
title
from
(
  SELECT
    ARRAY(SELECT transaction.transactionId FROM UNNEST(hits)
          WHERE transaction.transactionId = '03971163') AS title
  FROM `ga-export-TTTTT.1234567890.ga_sessions_*`
  )
WHERE ARRAY_LENGTH(title) > 0;
```

Would appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  ARRAY(SELECT transaction.transactionId
        FROM UNNEST(hits)
        WHERE transaction.transactionId = '03971163')
    AS transactionIds
FROM `ga-export-TTTT.1234567890.ga_sessions_*`;
```

When you use `CROSS JOIN` with an array, you get a row in the result for every array element. If you want a one-to-one correspondence with the rows in the table, you can use an array subquery (as in the query above) to "repackage" the array elements after applying a filter. As another example, you can use an `ARRAY` subquery along with `SELECT AS STRUCT`:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT transaction.*
        FROM UNNEST(hits)
        WHERE transaction.transactionId = '03971163')
    AS transactions
FROM `ga-export-TTTT.1234567890.ga_sessions_*`;
```

This will return an array of all of the fields inside `transaction` for hits matching the condition of `transaction.transactionId = '03971163'`. If you just want a single element of the array, you can use a subquery in the select list with a `LIMIT` instead:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
 (SELECT transaction.transactionId
  FROM UNNEST(hits)
  WHERE transaction.transactionId = '03971163'
  LIMIT 1)
    AS transactionId
FROM `ga-export-TTTT.1234567890.ga_sessions_*`;
```

Or:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
 (SELECT transaction
  FROM UNNEST(hits)
  WHERE transaction.transactionId = '03971163'
  LIMIT 1)
    AS transaction
FROM `ga-export-TTTT.1234567890.ga_sessions_*`;
```

Comment: Thanks @Elliott . Unfortunately this doesn't work. Both examples return enormous amount of rows, but should be just one.

Comment: The query I provided returns all of the elements of that array matching the transaction ID, which is what you asked for. If you just want one element of the array, use `LIMIT` instead; see my edit.

Comment: Hey @Elliot, my question was about how to get results similar to what i get using legacysql. Using Limit 1 will not work in this case.

Comment: You didn't provide a valid legacy SQL query in your question, so I don't know what results you expected.

Comment: You are right! Sorry copy-pasted wrong piece of code. Just updated the legacy sql in the query. @Elliot

Comment: I must be missing something--either your legacy SQL query was giving you more than one row, or the last query that I provided will still work if you remove the `LIMIT 1`. You also need to filter on `_TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '2016-09-01' AND '2017-02-14'`.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference in your two queries (for Legacy and Standard SQL versions) I see is that you potentially querying different set of tables!

In Legacy SQL Version – you limit tables list for time period from TIMESTAMP('2016-09-01') till TIMESTAMP('2017-02-14') whereas in Standard SQL you query all ga_sessions_ tables in `ga-export-TTTT.1234567890` dataset

Try below to filter tables to same list as in Legacy SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT hits2.transaction.transactionId as transactionId
FROM `ga-export-TTTT.1234567890.ga_sessions_*`, UNNEST (hits) as hits2
WHERE hits2.transaction.transactionId = '03971163'
AND _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20160901' AND '20170214'
```